# Memory efficient plain text viewer

Tags: windows

Is there a viewer that only ever loads a portion of the file in memory that corresponds to the GUI view area, maybe +/- one GUI screen, that also has regex search and syntax highlight and word wrap? I know FAR Manager's viewer does the memory thing and regex search, but it lacks other features and it's console window, whereas I'd like a GUI app.

For example, to view a 20 GB log file.

Comment: pretty much any viewers for any non-trivial formats will not load the whole file into memory if it's huge. For example no app will load all the pages on a 1000-page pdf file or docx file

Comment: @phuclv clarified the format and file size in the question

Comment: @phuclv gvim, for example, will load the whole file in memory, even in "view" mode, but it's not a viewer. "less" isn't a GUI app and it doesn't have syntax highlight. I tried LogExpert, but it loads the whole file into memory, becomes unresponsive and crashes. So when you say "any", can you give an least one example matching the specified criteria?

Comment: Sometimes `less` is more - it will do all of what you want EXCEPT syntax highlight.  Fire up the linux subsystem and use `less` or use `cygwin` and use `less` there, or use the gnu32 `less.exe` - http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/less.htm